# Regex matching 2 or more nested optional terms

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to parse this string using preg_match_all:

```
$str = "form.input|type()
        form.input|type('text')
        form.input|type('text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})
        form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})";

preg_match_all('/form\.input\|type\((?:(.*))?\)/', $str, $matches);
```

Expected output:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => form.input|type()
        [1] => form.input|type('text')
        [2] => form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})
        [3] => form.input|type('text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => text
        [2] => image
        [3] => text
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => {'path': '/path/to/image'}
        [3] => {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'}
    )
```

Real output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => form.input|type()
            [1] => form.input|type('text')
            [2] => form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})
            [3] => form.input|type('text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 'text'
            [2] => 'image', {'path': '/path/to/image'}
            [3] => 'text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'}
        )

)
```

This pattern can parse the cases:

```
form.input|type()
form.input|type('text')
```

I tried to match by this pattern:

```
/form\.input\|type\((?:(.*)(?:,(.*))?)?\)/
```

But it failed to match the pattern because of the child non capturing group.

I used non capturing group `(?:(.*))?` for optional matching but it can match only if there is no child non capturing group using the first pattern.

I tried to search about matching in this case but i couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: What do you expect as output? Your pattern matches all of the above cases: https://regex101.com/r/JLmX3Q/1 Or even [**`\Qform.input|type(\E(?:([^()]*))?\)`**](https://regex101.com/r/JLmX3Q/2)

Comment: @Jan I edited the question with the expected output.
This pattern matches all content inside type() as one string.
But i want to match them divided in 2 parts: the string type and the json options.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you dont want to match. From your example this is sufficient `/f.+/`

Comment: @miknik please can you apply it in the example?
/form\.input\|type\((?:(.*))?\)/

Comment: @semsem Your question says "_I want to parse this string using preg_match_" Well that is a little unclear to me.  Are you using `preg_match_all()` to extract the values from each line? or are these actually four separate sample strings and you want to call `preg_match()` on all four?  Please add your php implementation to the question to clarify the actual task?  Do you want to return 2 capture groups each time? even when one or both of the capture groups are empty?  These are all critical details that must be included in your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes i'm using preg_match_all()
I edited the question

Comment: Your question is unclear about how many lines are in a string.  Is the sample input a single string with four lines of text? Or four separate strings with one line of text in each?  Please show some php in your question.  If it is one string with 4 lines, what is expected?

Comment: @mickmackusa i edited the question with expected php input & output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggested pattern to handle single and double quoting: ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6TWPPm/3/))

```
/form\.input\|type\(['"]?([a-z]*)['"]?(?:, )?([^)]*)/
```

Pattern Explanation:

```
form\.input\|type\(  // Literally match the static/known leading characters
['"]?                // optionally match a single or double quote
([a-z]*)             // greedily capture zero or more lowercase letters
['"]?                // optionally match a single or double quote
(?:, )?              // optionally match a comma followed by a space
([^)]*)              // greedily capture zero or more non-closing parenthesis characters
```

Effectively, by using "zero or one" (`?`) or "zero or more" (`*`) quantifiers, strings can have empty or non-empty parenthetical components and ensure that both intended capture groups are delivered in the output array.

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bf6c01dcbadb94700c6665909f2d02bce608296))

```
$str = "form.input|type()   
        form.input|type('text')
        form.input|type(\"text\", {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})
        form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})";

print_r(preg_match_all("/form\.input\|type\(['\"]?([a-z]*)['\"]?(?:, )?([^)]*)/",$str,$out)?array_slice($out,1):'fail');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => text
            [2] => text
            [3] => image
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'}
            [3] => {'path': '/path/to/image'}
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of a regular expression and `explode()`:

```
<?php

$strings = ["form.input|type()","form.input|type('text')","form.input|type('text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})", "form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})']"];

$regex = '~\(([^()]+)\)~';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(", ", $match[1], 1);
        echo $key, $value . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/ocb9oj).

---

The idea here is to look for something inside `(` and `)` and then split/explode on the first `,` found. If you want to limit the expression to `form.input`, you could alter the expression to:

```
\Qform.input|type\E\(([^()]+)\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/JLmX3Q/3/).

---

### Addendum

To strip the quotes, one could use

```
<?php

$strings = ["form.input|type()",
                        "form.input|type('text')",
                        "form.input|type('text', {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'})", 
                        "form.input|type('image', {'path': '/path/to/image'})']",
                        "form.input|type(\"image\", {'path': '/path/to/image2'})']"];


$regex = '~\(([^()]+)\)~';
$key_value = '~^([\'"])(.+?)\1(?:, )?(.*)~';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $string, $match)) {
        if (preg_match($key_value, $match[1], $inner)) {
            $key = $inner[2];
            $value = $inner[3];
            echo "Key = $key, Value = $value\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Which yields

```
Key = text, Value = 
Key = text, Value = {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'}
Key = image, Value = {'path': '/path/to/image'}
Key = image, Value = {'path': '/path/to/image2'}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan, Is there a better way to remove single & double quotes in matched output strings than replacing them?
'text' and "text"

Answer (score 0):

This

```
preg_match_all('/((?<=\(\')\w+)|({.*})/', $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);

print_r($matches);
```

Will return this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] => text
[1] => {'width': '100px', 'height': '50px'}
)
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers -- ever.  They may solve the issue but they are low value and do very little to educate future readers.  Think of SO as a classroom with thousands of students.  Please update your answer.

Comment: @semsem this answer is incorrect, right?  Because it doesn't return any matches from the first sample string.  There is no php code in the question, so we don't know if you want to return 2 matches (potentially empty) each time or if you are handling a no match as a valid outcome for the first sample string. (`form.input|type()`)  Please clarify your expected output arrays for your 4 sample inputs.

Comment: @mickmackusa  this answer is not accurate.
I'm sorry i will edit the question to clarify with php code.